# Use third party libraries in Keycloak

Tags: apache-kafka, keycloak

I'd like to use kafka-clients for my keycloak module, in order to publish every login event into it.

The problem is in the deployment process : I used the "module way" for my custom keycloak providers packaged in a jar, declaring kafka-clients as a module dependency. As it doesn't exists, I also manually created a kafka-clients module. Still, I have issues on startup because of an unfound class :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory from [Module "org.apache.kafka.kafka-clients"
```

Maybe an other dependency is missing. Anyway, I don't want to handle all dependencies troubles manually.

So my question is : **What is the best way to deploy a custom keycloak SPI provider, requiring third party dependencies ?**

Should I build an EAR ? A WAR ? Is a JAR enough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JAR is enough if you add kafka-clients dependency to it.

You can have a look at how [keycloak-metrics-spi](https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/blob/a946877d812214338a0903d4fbc7fdd77d49209b/build.gradle) bundle prometeus dependencies in its own jar (using gradle)

```
configurations {
    bundleLib
}

dependencies {
    bundleLib group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_common', version: prometheusVersion
    bundleLib group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_hotspot', version: prometheusVersion
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.bundleLib)
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.bundleLib.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

An EAR would work too (and would allow you hot deployment), you only need to add kafka-clients to the lib directory of your archive.